# Variable in GraphQL Query

Tags: graphql

I am trying to use variables with GraphQL queries but the browser is responding with bad request.

here is my code

```
return this.apollo.query({
      query: gql `query Project($projectId: String!){
        project( where: { id: $projectId } )
          {
            id
            initials
          }
      }`,
      variables: { projectId: pid },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
  })
```

for some reason its not picking the project variable in the query. when i replace the variables with hard-coded values it works fine. 
can you please help me to understand why.

Comment: I found the issue with my code, actually projectId is a ID field in graphql and i was providing it as a string. I changed it to ID and it worked.

Comment: You can submit an answer to your own question and later mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code was with the data type of $projectId. this is an actual id in the database(i.e prisma in my case). so I changed the code to :

```
return this.apollo.query({
      query: gql `query Project($projectId: ID!){
        project( where: { id: $projectId } )
          {
            id
            initials
          }
      }`,
      variables: { projectId: pid },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
  })
```

and its working now.

I found graphql playground very helpful and providing variables in the bottom of the screen. that way you can debug the code faster